# Run-length decoding in MATLAB

Tags: performance, matlab, run-length-encoding

For clever usage of linear indexing or `accumarray`, I've sometimes felt the need to generate sequences based on [run-length encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding). As there is no built-in function for this, I am asking for the most efficient way to decode a sequence encoded in RLE.

### Specification:

As to make this a fair comparison I would like to set up some specifications for the function:

- If optional second argument `values` of same length is specified, the output should be according to those values, otherwise just the values `1:length(runLengths)`.
- Gracefully handle:

  - zeros in `runLengths`
  - `values` being a cell array.
- Output vector should have same column/row format as `runLengths`

In short: The function should be equivalent to the following code:

```
function V = runLengthDecode(runLengths, values)
[~,V] = histc(1:sum(runLengths), cumsum([1,runLengths(:).']));
if nargin>1
    V = reshape(values(V), 1, []);
end
V = shiftdim(V, ~isrow(runLengths));
end
```

### Examples:

Here are a few test cases

```
runLengthDecode([0,1,0,2])
runLengthDecode([0,1,0,4], [1,2,4,5].')
runLengthDecode([0,1,0,2].', [10,20,30,40])
runLengthDecode([0,3,1,0], {'a','b',1,2})
```

and their output:

```
>> runLengthDecode([0,1,0,2])
ans =
     2     4     4

>> runLengthDecode([0,1,0,4], [1,2,4,5].')
ans =    
     2     5     5     5     5

>> runLengthDecode([0,1,0,2].', [10,20,30,40])
ans =
    20
    40
    40

>> runLengthDecode([0,3,1,0],{'a','b',1,2})
ans = 
    'b'    'b'    'b'    [1]
```

Comment: It seems you just need to decorate [this question's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975772/matlab-array-manipulation) accepted answer with `varargins`.

Comment: @Divakar: Dang! Why can't questions with great answers simply be titled what I'm looking for!

Comment: @Divakar: Wait: The zeros don't really work, but it looks like a good first step.

Comment: A mask would make it work, use that as pre-processing at the start to alter both inputs.

Comment: @Divakar: Now that I've used the tag to search for run-length encoding, there's even a similar one [you answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26064172/repeat-elements-of-vector).

Comment: So.. is this a duplicate or not? I was devising an answer...

Comment: Anyway, your function seems to be efficient already, right?

Comment: @LuisMendo: I'm uncertain if we should close it as a duplicate. I was mainly thinking of a simple copy-paste solution if anyone was looking for run-length-decoding. And as I couldn't find one directly (only looking for the text, not the tag; now searching for the tag I've found plenty) I was thinking to produce a question that could be found more easily...

Comment: @LuisMendo: So gnovice's answer will be the fastest? It looks like you used it in a [recent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28499372/3139711), so I assume.

Comment: Hm. Neither of the other questions really clarifies what is the fastest solution and most of them don't handle zeros correctly. So I'm not perfectly content with closing the question.

Comment: Shall we create a community wiki answer to measure performance? We could include all other linked answers and compare. Maybe you can define some test cases. And I must tell you, the requirement to preserve `runLenghts` orientation in the result is painful :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo: Can I convert it somehow? I've never done community-wikis. Yes, the transposing is annoying, but I wanted to make the functionality more predictable :)

Comment: Please be more specific than 'most efficient'. At least give (the size of) your input and the 'efficiency' of your example solution.

Comment: @knedlsepp Creating a community wiki answer is easy. Just create the answer, and mark a "wiki" flag somewhere. Important points are: 1) Define test cases. 2) Decide who runs the tests: they should be done in the same computer, for consistency. Do you feel like doing it? Are you familiar with `timeit`? If not, I could write the benchmarking code

Comment: @LuisMendo: Oh, an answer to this question? You mean the tests should be run on http://ideone.com/ or on the persons own computer?

Comment: @LuisMendo: I've recently done a benchmarking-code for euclidean distances, so we could [harvest it](https://ideone.com/98YfXv).

Comment: @knedlsepp Yes, a wiki answer to this question. I'm not familiar with running code in ideone.com. I was thinking about a computer. Specifically your computer :-P

Comment: @LuisMendo: I could do it. So the benefit of making it a community answer is that if (theoretically) someone comes up with yet another competing solution, he can benchmark it and add it to the community-answer?

Comment: @knedlsepp I don't think there's any benefit; it just makes more sense, as no-one is "the author" and so no-one gets the reputation associated with that answer. And yes, everyone feels more free to edit that answer. Although in this case, if you're going to run the tests, that's not an advantage really

Comment: @knedlsepp I think this question should have received more attention, so I'm considering setting a bounty on it (after the compulsory two-day period). What do you think? I hope the system won't get suspicious that I set a bounty on a question which only I have answered :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo: Pro: If we attract more different answers, the runtime comparison would look more definite and the search for the *most efficient* solution can be ended, as we're being more exhaustive on the space of all possible solutions. Contra: I doubt that anybody will be able to improve much on *gnovice*'s answer. My two cents: I have really no idea if a bounty would change anything.

Comment: @knedlsepp Hm. I think I'll give it a try in one or two days

Comment: @knedlsepp Meta has [clarified](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286103/can-i-set-a-bounty-to-bring-attention-to-a-question-i-gave-an-answer-to) there's no problem in me offering a bounty on a question I have answered. So here it comes

Comment: @LuisMendo: I'll just put on [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VBlFHuCzPgY) and go into waiting mode. ;-)

Comment: With ML2015a `repelem` was added. Seems it does not support cells but I don't have this version to try it.

Comment: @Daniel: I guess it was time to introduce `repelem`; finally.

Comment: @knedlsepp Can you add `repelem` to your benchmarking?

Comment: @Dan: I actually don't have access to a MATLAB installation anymore. But feel free to edit the answer if you have!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To find out which one is the most efficient solution, we provide a test-script that evaluates the performance. The first plot depicts runtimes for growing length of the vector `runLengths`, where the entries are uniformly distributed with maximum length 200. A [modification of *gnovice*'s solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28615814/3139711) is the fastest, with *Divakar*'s solution being second place.
[image: Speed comparison]

This second plot uses nearly the same test data except it includes an initial run of length `2000`. This mostly affects both `bsxfun` solutions, whereas the other solutions will perform quite similarly.

[image: Speed comparison]

The tests suggest that a [modification](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28615814/3139711) of *gnovice*'s [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1975835/3139711) will be the most performant.

---

If you want to do the speed comparison yourself, here's the code used to generate the plot above.

```
function theLastRunLengthDecodingComputationComparisonYoullEverNeed()
Funcs =  {@knedlsepp0, ...
          @LuisMendo1bsxfun, ...
          @LuisMendo2cumsum, ...
          @gnovice3cumsum, ...
          @Divakar4replicate_bsxfunmask, ...
          @knedlsepp5cumsumaccumarray
          };    
%% Growing number of runs, low maximum sizes in runLengths
ns = 2.^(1:25);
paramGenerators{1} = arrayfun(@(n) @(){randi(200,n,1)}, ns,'uni',0);
paramGenerators{2} = arrayfun(@(n) @(){[2000;randi(200,n,1)]}, ns,'uni',0);
for i = 1:2
    times = compareFunctions(Funcs, paramGenerators{i}, 0.5);
    finishedComputations = any(~isnan(times),2);
    h = figure('Visible', 'off');
    loglog(ns(finishedComputations), times(finishedComputations,:));
    legend(cellfun(@func2str,Funcs,'uni',0),'Location','NorthWest','Interpreter','none');
    title('Runtime comparison for run length decoding - Growing number of runs');
    xlabel('length(runLengths)'); ylabel('seconds');
    print(['-f',num2str(h)],'-dpng','-r100',['RunLengthComparsion',num2str(i)]);
end
end

function times = compareFunctions(Funcs, paramGenerators, timeLimitInSeconds)
if nargin<3
    timeLimitInSeconds = Inf;
end
times = zeros(numel(paramGenerators),numel(Funcs));
for i = 1:numel(paramGenerators)
    Params = feval(paramGenerators{i});
    for j = 1:numel(Funcs)
        if max(times(:,j))<timeLimitInSeconds
            times(i,j) = timeit(@()feval(Funcs{j},Params{:}));
        else
            times(i,j) = NaN;
        end
    end
end
end
%% // #################################
%% // HERE COME ALL THE FANCY FUNCTIONS
%% // #################################
function V = knedlsepp0(runLengths, values)
[~,V] = histc(1:sum(runLengths), cumsum([1,runLengths(:).']));%'
if nargin>1
    V = reshape(values(V), 1, []);
end
V = shiftdim(V, ~isrow(runLengths));
end

%% // #################################
function V = LuisMendo1bsxfun(runLengths, values)
nn = 1:numel(runLengths);
if nargin==1 %// handle one-input case
    values = nn;
end
V = values(nonzeros(bsxfun(@times, nn,...
    bsxfun(@le, (1:max(runLengths)).', runLengths(:).'))));
if size(runLengths,1)~=size(values,1) %// adjust orientation of output vector
    V = V.'; %'
end
end

%% // #################################
function V = LuisMendo2cumsum(runLengths, values)
if nargin==1 %// handle one-input case
    values = 1:numel(runLengths);
end
[ii, ~, jj] = find(runLengths(:));
V(cumsum(jj(end:-1:1))) = 1;
V = values(ii(cumsum(V(end:-1:1))));
if size(runLengths,1)~=size(values,1) %// adjust orientation of output vector
    V = V.'; %'
end
end

%% // #################################
function V = gnovice3cumsum(runLengths, values)
isColumnVector =  size(runLengths,1)>1;
if nargin==1 %// handle one-input case
    values = 1:numel(runLengths);
end
values = reshape(values(runLengths~=0),1,[]);
if isempty(values) %// If there are no runs
    V = []; return;
end
runLengths = nonzeros(runLengths(:));
index = zeros(1,sum(runLengths));
index(cumsum([1;runLengths(1:end-1)])) = 1;
V = values(cumsum(index));
if isColumnVector %// adjust orientation of output vector
    V = V.'; %'
end
end
%% // #################################
function V = Divakar4replicate_bsxfunmask(runLengths, values)
if nargin==1   %// Handle one-input case
    values = 1:numel(runLengths);
end

%// Do size checking to make sure that both values and runlengths are row vectors.
if size(values,1) > 1
    values = values.'; %//'
end
if size(runLengths,1) > 1
    yes_transpose_output = false;
    runLengths = runLengths.'; %//'
else
    yes_transpose_output = true;
end

maxlen = max(runLengths);

all_values = repmat(values,maxlen,1);
%// OR all_values = values(ones(1,maxlen),:);

V = all_values(bsxfun(@le,(1:maxlen)',runLengths)); %//'

%// Bring the shape of V back to the shape of runlengths
if yes_transpose_output
    V = V.'; %//'
end
end
%% // #################################
function V = knedlsepp5cumsumaccumarray(runLengths, values)
isRowVector = size(runLengths,2)>1;
%// Actual computation using column vectors
V = cumsum(accumarray(cumsum([1; runLengths(:)]), 1));
V = V(1:end-1);
%// In case of second argument
if nargin>1
    V = reshape(values(V),[],1);
end
%// If original was a row vector, transpose
if isRowVector
    V = V.'; %'
end
end
```

Comment: Do you think it's a good idea to use `feval` within `timeit`? Won't that time affected by `'feval'`s overhead? I usually build an anonymous function or handle and feed that into `timeit`

Comment: @LuisMendo: The performance difference is not measurable for me if compared to `timeit(@()Funcs{j}(Params{:}))`, sometimes even `feval` is faster.

Comment: @LuisMendo: Great, I'll just add the resulting plot.

Comment: @knedlsepp We should perhaps add a version based on gnovice's approach. I can do that if you want (I don't want to keep throwing you things to do!), I mean write the function in the wiki answer.

Comment: @LuisMendo: Ok, just tell me when you've got the code so I can regenerate the plot. I just quickly add my edit that exports the figure without need to open the matlab gui.

Comment: @knedlsepp It turns out Gnovice's approach doesn't work when `runLengths` has zeros. Of course that could be fixed, but doing so requires significant modification. So I think it's not worth the effort

Comment: @LuisMendo: How about what Divakar suggested to simply go with a preprocessing mask before anything else: `values = values(runLengths~=0); runLengths = nonzeros(runLengths);`?

Comment: @knedlsepp Of course! I hadn't realized it was so simple!

Comment: @LuisMendo: The only annoying part is making `runLengths==0` work.

Comment: I've edited this answer to incorporate Gnovice's approach with the suggestions by Divakar and by you. I also changed my two solutions: there was an error in the final `if`, which sometimes didn't preserve orientation. Sorry about that. I said that part was painful... :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo: Great! Then here I come!

Comment: @LuisMendo: Finally. I did make a few alterations to *gnovice*'s code, to get rid of the second copy of `runLengths2` and to make it work for `runLengths==0`. Seems it is quite a bit faster than the other solutions. The memory overhead can't be seen from the plot, but I guess with the possible exception of `bsxfun` if there is one run that's a lot longer than the others, they will all perform quite the same. I would have liked if the code of this version came out cleaner, but well, that's a tradeoff for speed I guess.

Comment: @knedlsepp [This](http://postimg.org/image/c32m3nrlx/) is what I got after adding mine into the list, for `ns = 2.^(1:20)`.

Comment: @Divakar: I get similar results on my machine. You came quite close! I'd be happy if you'd add it to the wiki! Wait? So on your machine *Luis*' answers are slower than `histc`? Odd...

Comment: @knedlsepp Yup, that looks odd. Could you do one pass on this at your end ? Also, I have just updated tiny bit of my function code and here's the updated runtimes - http://postimg.org/image/yj6f9xk0p/

Comment: @Divakar: For this test-case on my machine your solution is faster than *gnovice*'s!! I will add the code to the wiki. (I guess I should however add somehow, that there will be significant performance drops if there is one runlength that is relatively large, like in `paramGenerators = arrayfun(@(n) @(){[2000;randi(200,n,1)]}, ns,'uni',0);`)

Comment: @knedlsepp Exactly, that's really the catch with repmatting and using mask!

Comment: @Divakar: I did add your code and a second plot with a slight modification of the input data just to show the limits of `bsxfun`. Oh, you already commented. Nevermind.

Answer (score 5):

### Approach 1

This should be reasonably fast. It uses
[`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to create a matrix of size `numel(runLengths)`x`numel(runLengths)`, so it may not be suitable for huge input sizes.

```
function V = runLengthDecode(runLengths, values)
nn = 1:numel(runLengths);
if nargin==1 %// handle one-input case
    values = nn;
end
V = values(nonzeros(bsxfun(@times, nn,...
    bsxfun(@le, (1:max(runLengths)).', runLengths(:).'))));
if size(runLengths,1)~=size(values,1) %// adjust orientation of output vector
    V = V.';
end
```

### Approach 2

This approach, based on [`cumsum`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html), is an adaptation of that used in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28499372/2586922). It uses less memory than approach 1.

```
function V = runLengthDecode2(runLengths, values)
if nargin==1 %// handle one-input case
    values = 1:numel(runLengths);
end
[ii, ~, jj] = find(runLengths(:));
V(cumsum(jj(end:-1:1))) = 1;
V = values(ii(cumsum(V(end:-1:1))));
if size(runLengths,1)~=size(values,1) %// adjust orientation of output vector
    V = V.';
end
```

Comment: @knedlsepp Yes, gnovice's approach is probably faster

Answer (score 5):

As of R2015a, the function `repelem` is the best choice to do this:

```
function V = runLengthDecode(runLengths, values)
if nargin<2
    values = 1:numel(runLengths);
end
V = repelem(values, runLengths);
end
```

---

For versions before R2015a this is a fast alternative:

### Alternative to `repelem`:

I had the feeling *gnovice*'s approach could be improved upon by using a better zero-runLength fix than the preprocessing mask.
So I gave `accumarray` a shot. It seems this gives the solution yet another boost:

```
function V = runLengthDecode(runLengths, values)
%// Actual computation using column vectors
V = cumsum(accumarray(cumsum([1; runLengths(:)]), 1));
V = V(1:end-1);
%// In case of second argument
if nargin>1
    V = reshape(values(V),[],1);
end
%// If original was a row vector, transpose
if size(runLengths,2)>1
    V = V.'; %'
end
end
```

Comment: Looks promising indeed from the new runtime plots!

Comment: @LuisMendo: Well, thanks for all the internet coins then! :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo:  It seems it wasn't enough incentive for anybody else to add their solutions though...

Comment: @knedlsepp Well, Divakar did contribute, and the question has been viewed over 250 times! :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo: Oh yeah, forgot you set the bounty before Divakar joined in.

Answer (score 4):

The solution presented here basically does the `run-length decoding` in two steps -

1. Replicate all `values` upto the maximum number of `runLengths`.
2. Use [**`bsxfun`**](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)'s masking capability to select from each column the corresponding `runlengths`.

Rest of the stuffs inside the function code are to take care of the input and output sizes to satisfy the requirements set in the question.

The function code listed next would be a "cleaned-up" version of [one of my previous answers to a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26064583/3293881). Here's the code -

```
function V = replicate_bsxfunmask(runLengths, values)

if nargin==1   %// Handle one-input case
    values = 1:numel(runLengths);
end

%// Do size checking to make sure that both values and runlengths are row vectors.
if size(values,1) > 1
    values = values.'; %//'
end
if size(runLengths,1) > 1
    yes_transpose_output = false;
    runLengths = runLengths.'; %//'
else
    yes_transpose_output = true;
end

maxlen = max(runLengths);

all_values = repmat(values,maxlen,1);
%// OR all_values = values(ones(1,maxlen),:);

V = all_values(bsxfun(@le,(1:maxlen)',runLengths)); %//'

%// Bring the shape of V back to the shape of runlengths
if yes_transpose_output
    V = V.'; %//'
end

return;
```

---

The code listed next would be a hybrid (`cumsum` + `replicate_bsxfunmask`) and would be suitable when you have a good number of outliers or really huge outliers. Also to keep it simple, for now this works on numeric arrays only. Here's the implementation -

```
function out = replicate_bsxfunmask_v2(runLengths, values)

if nargin==1                       %// Handle one-input case
    values = 1:numel(runLengths);
end

if size(values,1) > 1
    values = values.';  %//'
end

if size(runLengths,1) > 1
    yes_transpose_output = true;
    runLengths = runLengths.';  %//'
else
    yes_transpose_output = false;
end

%// Regularize inputs
values = values(runLengths>0);
runLengths = runLengths(runLengths>0);

%// Main portion of code
thresh = 200; %// runlengths threshold that are to be processed with cumsum

crunLengths = cumsum(runLengths); %%// cumsums of runlengths
mask = runLengths >= thresh; %// mask of runlengths above threshold
starts = [1 crunLengths(1:end-1)+1]; %// starts of each group of runlengths

mask_ind = find(mask); %// indices of mask

post_mark = starts(mask);
negt_mark = crunLengths(mask)+1;

if  ~isempty(negt_mark) && negt_mark(end) > crunLengths(end)
    negt_mark(end) = [];
end

%// Create array & set starts markers for starts of runlengths above thresh
marked_out = zeros(1,crunLengths(end));
marked_out(post_mark) = mask_ind;
marked_out(negt_mark) = marked_out(negt_mark) -1*mask_ind(1:numel(negt_mark));

%// Setup output array with the cumsumed version of marked array
out = cumsum(marked_out);

%// Mask for final ouput to decide between large and small runlengths
thresh_mask = out~=0;

%// Fill output array with cumsum and then rep-bsxfun based approaches
out(thresh_mask) = values(out(thresh_mask));

values = values(~mask);
runLengths = runLengths(~mask);

maxlen = max(runLengths);
all_values = repmat(values,maxlen,1);
out(~thresh_mask) = all_values(bsxfun(@le,(1:maxlen)',runLengths)); %//'

if yes_transpose_output
    out = out.';  %//'
end

return;
```

Comment: I was expecting an answer from you! Great job, very fast!

Comment: Perhaps you could save some time by using the trick you suggested regarding Gnovices' approach? That is, use only the non-zero values of `runLengths`. That way you would avoid all-zero columns in `bsxfun(@le,(1:maxlen)',runLengths)`. Not sure it that would speed or slow things, though

Comment: This is good code until memory becomes an issue, or there are large outliers in the runlengths as pointed out by @knedlsepp... You can mitigate this by checking max array size left with `memory` then blocklooping over blocks of size: max array divided by max runlength... I've implemented the solution if anyone cares, I could post it if necessary. There could even be ways of adaptively blocklooping in function of the maximum runlength in the next block which would be computationally very efficient I think and even smarter, but no time to explore that...

Comment: @reverse_engineer Well I did try with a hybrid approach (cumsum + replicate_bsxfunmask) and the runtimes seemed to be really bad, still I have added that here. Still, would be interesting to see what you have in mind, so maybe post what you tried?

Comment: @LuisMendo Well I did try with a hybrid approach (cumsum + replicate_bsxfunmask) and the runtimes seemed to be really bad, at least for the original data-generated model of randi(200,n,1), still have added that here!