# Kronecker product with varying dimension in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a vector in Matlab `A` of dimension `mx1` reporting the natural integers from `1` to `m` in increasing order, e.g. `A=[1 2 3]'`.

Let `B` be a vector of dimension `mx1` reporting some natural integers greater or equal than zero, e.g. `B=[1 3 0]'`.

Without using loops, I want to construct a vector `C` of dimension `sum_i(B(i))` obtained by listing each `A(i)` `B(i)` times. In the example
`C=[1 2 2 2]`.

Comment: I think this is what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28501418/run-length-decoding-in-matlab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `arrayfun`

```
A = [1 2 3]';
B = [1 3 0]';
m = 3;
C = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x) ones(B(x),1)*A(x), 1:m, 'UniformOutput', 0)');

C =

     1
     2
     2
     2
```