# Sort array elements by the frequency of its elements

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, octave

Is it possible in matlab/octave to use the `sort` function to sort an array based on the relative frequency of their elements?

For example the array

```
m= [4,4,4,10,10,10,4,4,5]
```

should result in this array:

```
[5,10,10,10,4,4,4,4,4]
```

`5` is the less frequent element and is on the top while `4` is the most frequent and it's on bottom.
Should one use the indices provided by `histcount`?

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to use `accumarray` to find the count of each number (I suspect you can use `histcounts(m,max(m)))` but then you have to clear all the `0`s).

```
m = [4,4,4,10,10,10,4,4,5];

[~,~,subs]=unique(m);
freq = accumarray(subs,subs,[],@numel);
[~,i2] = sort(freq(subs),'descend');

m(i2)
```

---

By combinging my approach with that of [m.s.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31671923/1011724) you can get a simpler solution:

```
m = [4,4,4,10,10,10,4,4,5];

[U,~,i1]=unique(m);
freq= histc(m,U);
[~,i2] = sort(freq(i1),'descend');

m(i2)
```

Answer (score 3):

The following code first calculates how often each element occurs and then uses `runLengthDecode` to expand the unique elements.

```
m = [4,4,4,10,10,10,4,4,5];

u_m = unique(m);

elem_count = histc(m,u_m);
[elem_count, idx] = sort(elem_count);

m_sorted = runLengthDecode(elem_count, u_m(idx));
```

---

The definition of `runLengthDecode` is copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28615814/678093):

For MATLAB R2015a+:

```
function V = runLengthDecode(runLengths, values)
if nargin<2
    values = 1:numel(runLengths);
end
V = repelem(values, runLengths);
end
```

---

For versions before R2015a:

```
function V = runLengthDecode(runLengths, values)
%// Actual computation using column vectors
V = cumsum(accumarray(cumsum([1; runLengths(:)]), 1));
V = V(1:end-1);
%// In case of second argument
if nargin>1
    V = reshape(values(V),[],1);
end
%// If original was a row vector, transpose
if size(runLengths,2)>1
    V = V.'; %'
end
end
```

Comment: You should post the actual code for `runlegnthDecode` in your answer in addition to the link you already have... also note `repelem` is quite a recent function so this won't work on older versions of Matlab (however it is not hard to make it work). Although by combining our two answers, you could avoid using that `runlengthDecode` by just using sort...

Comment: @Dan I copied the code from the original answer; it does not necessarily depend on `repelem`.

Answer (score 2):

You could count the number of repetitions with [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html), [`sort`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) that, and apply that sorting to `m`:

```
[~, ind] = sort(sum(bsxfun(@eq,m,m.')));
result = m(ind);
```