# specific multisets comparison

Tags: matlab, multiset

I am looking for vectorized matlab function to solve following problem:

I have sorted multiset `T = [1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3]`

and sorted submultiset `V` of `T` (`length(V)` is always smaller than `length(T)` )

```
V = [ 1 1 1 2]
```

I need to find logical vector

```
D = [1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0]
```

where `length(D) = length(T)` and `T(D) = V`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a good performance, my Idea would be to work with the histograms, thus have a smaller data size:

```
T = [1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3];
V = [ 1 1 1 2];
%Get list of all symbols
E=unique(T);
hT=hist(T,E);
hV=hist(V,E);
rep=[hV;hT-hV];
%Next two lines are taken from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/28615814/2732801
R=mod(cumsum(accumarray(cumsum([1; rep(:)]), 1)),2);
R=R(1:end-1);
```

Instead of the last two lines the matlab function `repelem` might be used:

```
R=mod(repelem(1:numel(rep),rep(:)),2);
```

Comment: How exactly use the repelem function?

Comment: @michal: My matlab version is to old to have this function, I do not know. Maybe someone else can answer this.

Comment: Is there any simple vectorized way how to generalize this solution for list of V = [1 1 1 2; 1 1 2 2; 1 2 2 2], for example?

Comment: Why do you expect it to be faster? It's just the difference if you define the bins using edges or centers.

Comment: Regarding your previous commend and a vectorized version for multiple V. For that data representation I have no better Idea than looping. Where does the V come from, maybe you can switch to a representation like`V = [3 1; 2 2; 1 3]`? (Same meaning, just count the numbers instead of repeating them)

Comment: histc is built-in function, hist perform many additional steps in hist.m file.

Comment: The overhead should be irrelevant