# Repeating elements of one vector according to a second

Tags: matlab, vector, rep

In MATLAB, if `N = 2` this is the line I need:

```
M = [V(1)*ones(1,L(1)) V(2)*ones(1,L(2))];
```

If `N = 3`, the line is:

```
M = [V(1)*ones(1,L(1)) V(2)*ones(1,L(2)) V(3)*ones(1,L(3))];
```

How could I write a line producing the same results for an arbitrary `N`?

Comment: What you want is run-length decoding. Here are some approaches: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28501418/run-length-decoding-in-matlab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
M = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(v,len) v*ones(1,len), V, L, 'uni', 0));
```

example:

```
>> V=3:5
V =
     3     4     5
>> L=1:3
L =
     1     2     3
>> M=cell2mat(arrayfun(@(v,len) v*ones(1,len), V, L, 'uni', 0))
M =
     3     4     4     5     5     5
```

Comment: `v + zeros(1,len)` is going to be faster than `v*ones(1,len)` http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/allocation-performance-take-2

Answer (score 4):

Since R2015a you can just use the built-in [`repelem`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html) function:

```
M = repelem(V,L)
```

or if `numel(V)` does not equal `N`

```
M = repelem(V(1:N),L(1:N))
```

If you have an older version of MATLAB, consider a simple loop

```
M = zeros(1, sum(L(1:N)));  %// preallocation
from = 1;
for elem = 1:N
    to = from + L(elem) - 1;
    M(from:to) = v(elem)*ones(1,L(elem));
    from = to + 1;
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but I use an older MATLAB version, namely 2012b.